# Get a part of a String using C#

Tags: c#, string

I have to get a little piece of a String, something like this:

```
20T41
```

Always are two numbers, a letter and numbers.

But **I have many different chains like these**:

- PNC **20T17**
- PNC **19T1391**
- P.N.C **19T1456**
- NC - **19T1099** divided
- PNC **19T323** - Without op.
- **19T1512**. Irregular

I have used some codes like this, but I don't know how I can do this for each case. I think it is better than using many IFs.

```
str = str.Substring (0, str.LastIndexOf ('/') + 1);
```

Marked in black is the String I want to get. I was thinking of doing something if, but this is not efficient. What do you recommend to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to use `Regex` for that?

Comment: `str = Regex.Match(str, "[0-9]{2}T[0-9]+").Value;`

Comment: tip: if you're having difficulty formatting the examples: indent them 4 characters (or select the block and press ctrl+k); right now you're looking for a forward slash, but none of your text *contains* a forward slash

Comment: usually you need to find something that is fixed when looking for a pattern. is the `T` always after 2 digits? or can that differ? It is also possible to be solved without regular expressions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try *matching* the fragment with a help of *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

str = Regex.Match(str, "[0-9]{2}T[0-9]+").Value;
```

Or in case of *any* (not necessary `T`) capital letter can appear:

```
str = Regex.Match(str, "[0-9]{2}[A-Z][0-9]+").Value;
```

Comment: Dmitry thanks a lot, but if I the letter can be in capital letter or lowercase letter, how can I difference it?

Comment: @LuckWallace `[Tt]` => means one of the letters\characters inside the set of `[  ]`

Answer (score 1):

The following [`Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8) expression will also help

```cs
var regex = new Regex("\\d{2}\\w\\d+");
var input = new List<string>()
    {"PNC 20T17", "PNC 19T1391", "P.N.C 19T1456,", "NC - 19T1099", "PNC 19T323", "19T1512."};

foreach (var item in input)
{
    var match = regex.Match(item);
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

It produces the following output

```
20T17
19T1391
19T1456
19T1099
19T323
19T1512
```

You can have a look at [`quick reference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) to see the meaning of every class inside

- `\d{2}` decimal digit, two times exactly
- `\w` any word character, capital or not
- `\d+` decimal digit one or more times. You can change it to `\d{1,}` or `\d{2,}`. It means matching the digit at least one or two times, without upper bounds, which isn't specified in OP. Or use upper bounds, like `\d{1,9}`

Answer (score 0):

IF the examples you provided are all combinations then `LastIndexOf` and `Substring` would do the work;

```cs
var yourInput = "P.N.C 19T1456";
var res = yourInput.Substring(yourInput.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1) ;
```